# How to understand "reference" in Object Oriented Programming?

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, oop

I am new to iOS development. From the very beginning of my study, I often meet the word "reference" in Apple's Official Document. In my Java leaning, I also met this word. I think this is an essential concept in OOP, but I can't understand it well. So can anybody interpret it for me? (would appreciate it more if you put up some example).
Thanks a lot!.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your nickname here is `Reggie`, obviously.

On some other forum you might be called `Reg`, because they have some weird limitations on usernames (no more than 3 symbols, how about that?) Some other community might know you as `Reginald`, because you decide to go full official on them.

And, of course, you might have some other names. All those names, however, *refer* to the same person - you.

The point is, you might have different references pointing to the same object in your program, which allows more flexible object manipulation.

Comment: A pointer is a reference! But there are other types of references. Read the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 2):

A reference is the physical address of where the data is stored in memory or in the storage device.

Example:

```
A a = new A();
```

Here lets say A is stored at memory location `1000` so the address of A is `1000`.

Now you are assigning `a` to some other variable:

```
A b = a;
```

Keep in mind here you are assigning the reference of `a` to `b` so now both points to the same address. If you modify anything in `a` or `b` it would be equivalent to saying that you are modifying the value at address location `1000`, so both `a` and `b` would be modified.

**So reference is nothing but address of an object**